# Android, BottomNavigation : Cannot set a gradient as a background on a bottomNavigationvieww

Tags: android, material-design, gradient, bottomnavigationview

I am trying to set the following gradient xml as a background to the `BottomNavigationView`

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:centerColor="#C6426E"
        android:endColor="#642B73"
        android:startColor="#C2185B"/>
    <solid android:color="#3f5063" />
</shape>
```

`android:background="@drawable/gradient"`is not working how do I make it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get rid of the solid color:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:centerColor="#C6426E"
        android:endColor="#642B73"
        android:startColor="#C2185B"/>
</shape>
```